# UPDATE mysql record from php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not a coder by any means. This is not my own code, I got it off Google but I believe it serves my purpose. I am trying to update a mysql record via php. It doesn't work!! This does nothing to the database.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","radius","radius","radius");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE userinfo SET enableportallogin=1 WHERE city='NULL'");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you check error using `mysqli_error($con);` ?

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string with 4 letters in it. `NULL` (note the lack of quotes) is an SQL null, the "unknown" value.

Answer (score 3):

if `NULL` is really `NULL` (*not as string*), you should use `IS NULL` to check for its value,

```
UPDATE userinfo SET enableportallogin = 1 WHERE city IS NULL
```

- [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE userinfo SET enableportallogin=1 WHERE city IS NULL");
```

Null isn't a value; it's a state of "not having a value". Hard to explain, but basically the problem in your original is:

1. MySQL (and others) always use `value IS NULL` and not `value = NULL`.
2. `NULL` can't be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
"UPDATE userinfo SET enableportallogin='1' WHERE city IS NULL"
```

You are trying to consider NULL as a value which is not in real :)

Answer (score 1):

In this query, use IS NULL for comparing city values.

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE userinfo SET enableportallogin=1 WHERE city is NULL");
```

While using this, also check the default value of city field in your schema.

For more reference, refer this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html